# How to use Azure Databricks Delta Lake Linked Service to Insert or update data in Delta table

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

We are tried to created Azure Databricks Delta Lake linked Service which is connected Delta Lake with databricks. we would like to use this service in dataset to insert or update the data on the delta table.

now, which activity component suitable for us and what is the best practice to provide the solution.

ultimately, we are planning to do the audit log purpose, so that needs to insert azure data factory pipeline details into delta table and as well as databricks notebook, we have some API calls to track the status and then put into table.

in this case, we would request, how to do we use delta table in ADF and databricks notebook at a time. also, which activity needs to use in ADF side, kindly suggest and help us.

currently, we are logging the audit logs in azure SQL DB, so that we are using LookUp activity to execute our Stored Procedure, the stored Procedure, we are passing as a parameter to insert or update our each pipeline execution.

our new requirement is instead of Azure SQL, we may have to use azure delta table to use ADF pipeline details needs to pass the parameter to execute insert operation and next activity will be notebook(ADB), this will execute notebook and inside notebook we are calling API,that API status we are planning to insert the logs(status) in same delta table which is using in ADF.

I am attached images which is older approach for your reference
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure Databricks Delta lake linked service only supports Copy activity, lookup activity and Mapping Dataflow.

I have tried insert query  with a sample select at the end with lookup activity, but it is not working even though the same query is working fine in normal databricks SQL. Databricks insert queries might be different in lookup activity case.

So, you can try the below two possible approaches to achieve your requirement.

1. If you want to use only **Azure Databricks Delta lake linked service**, you can try this method. But, for this method, it requires a storage account as staging location.
   Use copy activity to copy the data to Delta table.

   - Use the **Azure Databricks Delta lake** dataset with target table name for both source and sink of the copy activity. In source of the copy activity, use select query like below for sample.

   ```
   select  <value>  as <column_name>,<value>  as <column_name>,..;
   ```

   - In the value, **you need to use the pipeline information(pipeline name or id from dynamic content)** and in the column name give the same column name as your delta table.
   - As mentioned earlier, this requires a storage account linked service as staging location.Also, you need to set the spark configuration for that particular storage account at cluster level. Go though this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-databricks-delta-lake?tabs=data-factory#direct-copy-to-delta-lake) for better understanding about this.
2. If you want to avoid the usage of storage account, you can try the below approach which uses Notebook activity to achieve your requirement.

   Use a notebook activity to insert the data into your delta table. Create your delta table first and then use this.
   I have created a sample delta table for demo.

   ```
   %sql
   CREATE TABLE table1 (
         id int,
         name STRING,
         age int,
         hire_date DATE
   ) USING DELTA;
   ```

   In the Notebook activity, pass the pipeline information using base parameters like below sample.
   [image]

   In Notebook, use below code which gets the values as widgets from the above and inserts into the delta table.

   ```
   %sql
   insert into table1 values (${id},'${name}',${age},'${hire_date}')
   ```

   You can see my sample delta table values were inserted after pipeline run.

   [image]